# How can I define an array filled with a single value in AMPL

Tags: ampl

How can I define an unary or multidimensional array filled with one value in AMPL?
Is there something like this?

```
param ARRAY {i in 1..1000} [i] := 20;
```

Should result in:

```
[20, 20, 20, ..., 20]
```

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, but I'll throw in a couple of extra options:

```
param ARRAY{i in 1..1000} := 20;
# sets all values to 20

param ARRAY{i in 1..1000} default 20;
# sets all values to 20 unless otherwise specified 

param ARRAY{i in 1..1000};
for{i in 1..1000} {let ARRAY[i] = 20};
# iterates over the specified set.
# more useful if you want to do something like i^2 instead of a constant.
```

If you use the `default 20` method, then `display ARRAY;` will only show the values that have been changed from default - it will look as if ARRAY is empty, but referencing specific elements will work OK.